# Why my Ubuntu 14.04 does not detect home Wifi?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

I have installed ubuntu14.04 in my system. I am unable to detect wifi in my system. How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are person using ubuntu 16.04 who landed on this page like me, I leave the below link that solved the problem for me as a reference:

https://askubuntu.com/a/764120/658492

Solution: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score -1):

Go to **System Settings->Software&Updates->Additional Drivers**

There you will find "broadcam wireless driver" and enable it

you should connect with ethernet cable before doing this.

Comment: Why do you think OP has a Broadcom device?

Comment: There are a whole lot of different devices available (including a lot that don't even have a working driver for Linux).. Until the original poster gives more details, it's not possibly to reliably recommend anything.