# need to restart network-manager after upgrading to xenial xerus

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

I recently upgraded my toshiba satellite Pro L640 laptop to ubuntu 16.04. After resuming from suspend the network manager stops working, I am unable to see any wifi routers within range. I have to go to the terminal and issue this command `sudo service network-manager restart` to get it working. Any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: My macbook was running 16.04 and I didn't have this issue but following some recent updates, I'm now having this issue as well.

Comment: This is a duplicate, a solution has been suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade

Comment: try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I am working with ubuntu mate 16.04 and the same problem. This is a bug, and you can resume by running

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Waiting for this bug to be corrected, I have wrote the line

```
service network-manager restart
```

(without sudo) in my `/etc/rc.local` file.

This way the command is launched each time I start my session...
To modify the file, we can edit with something like

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Hope network-manager will be updated soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an up/down (Ethernet) icon instead of wireless, no wifi SSIDs appear in the list or connection drops (even while applet shows connected), [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1574347) is probably the bug, and is still being processed :(

Comment: Yes, it is as you described

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: I've been using some of the workarounds I found in other "no wifi after suspend" questions, but I wouldn't recommend them now, since they are releasing new fixed versions of the network-manager package quite often to solve the problem. It should be fixed soon, I think. Anyway, you can try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/761220/547672) script to restore connection automatically.  It automates "sudo systemctl restart network-manager" and check [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/768268/547672) answer too.