# No internet access Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet

just installed 16.04 NOT up-graded (no windows on disk) cannot connect to the internet - icon is there top right.  when first installed when icon was clicked it showed Ethernet connected (no cable was connected) 
      have tried to make Wifi and Ethernet connections but no joy (Router has a 20 letter/number code      For info  "EthernetNetwork" , "disconnected" and "Connection Information" all grayed out  I have a windows computer to down load etc.   any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: I believe this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues/768268#comment1186039_768268) can help you.

Comment: I think is the same issue of the question refered in the post before.

Comment: Typed the code in terminal results are

Comment: 04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductoer Co. Ltd   RTL8111/8168/8411  PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)    Subsystem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. P8P67 and other mother boards Kernel driver in use: r8169

Comment: Hope this helps and thankyou VERY much

Comment: have chk'd other questions sadley not the same problem   have seen some comments  in light of this have typed in terminal the following code   "iw reg get" and got this back    "country 00: DFS-UNSET" I'm in france should the country be 33   (it should be noted that I'm a beginner with ubuntu and still learning at 72)  thanking you all for your time and patience

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the windows computer is connected by WiFi to router - in ubuntu when clicking on icon and edit conections  WiFi and ethernet connections shows up but clicking on icon only the WiFi is shown   cable has been chk'd (new cable unused) all OK and connected

Comment: just typed in "iwconfig" and got the following: enp4s0    no wireless extensions  and   lo   no wireless extensions      hope this helps

Comment: @Joe, did you try `killall nm-applet && nm-applet & `? It may correct the wrong network icon.

Comment: I've had similar problems you've related. Most of them was correct with the first update. Have you done it?

Comment: Sorry thought I chk'd answers to me they were all different ----however problem solved  - formatted HD moved PC to connect Erthernet re-installed ubuntu all good----- A big thankyou to gwarah for trying to help

Comment: Restart all over again sometimes is the best solution. Nice it's solved. Don't forget first update. Solve a lot of little bugs. Well @Joe good luck from now on.