# Ubuntu16.04 wired connection not working after suspend

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, suspend, wired

I have a dell vostro 14-5480 laptop installed Ubuntu 16.04. I recognize that after suspend, my wired connection does not work anymore. I tried restart network-manager service by `sudo service network-manager restart` and a solution from [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html) and also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues) but none of them solves the problem.
Here is my result from `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:47:47:63:b9:b3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7204000-f7204fff memory:f7200000-f7203fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 59
       serial: 60:57:18:be:2e:5e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7100000-f7101fff
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution is that it needs to install r8168 driver.

Just run `sudo apt install r8168-dkms` and restart the computer.

Comment: Also worked for my HP Elitebook, same Ethernet HW, running Ubuntu 16.10/17.04. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dell XPS 15 (L502X) checking in on Ubuntu 17.04. Seems to have worked.

Comment: Also work for Ubuntu 18.04. This is nicer than download the r8168 from realtek website and rebuild the kernel