# Wifi only able to connect with one router after reinstall to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I made an update to Ubuntu 16 where I at the same time cleaned my computer (Lenovo X230) totally for previous settings and documents. During the installation I was asked to connect to my wifi and I connected to my Wifi at home. (There was a list of many options from my neighbours available).

The problem is whenever I turn on my computer at other places than at home the computer doesn't seem to recognize any wifi options at all.
When I'm home and turn on my computer it automatically connect to my home connection and I'm also able to see all the other wifi hotspots around as soon I’m connected to my home wifi.

I have tried

> sudo service network-manager restart

without any luck

I have a Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 driver.

When I go to “additional drivers” there is only something called “processor microcode firmware for intel cpus”. I have just read other threads suggesting that you can turn on the wifi-driver.

I’m able to connect to a wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

Form what I've experienced, this is a current issue in Ubuntu 16's networking with laptops of various companies including Lenovo. For the meantime, I put this in my `.bashrc` file and then just enter `restart-networking` into the terminal whenever I bring my laptop to a new router.

`alias restart-networking='sudo service network-manager restart'`

It's not the prettiest solution but it works well for many including myself.

Here's the best piece of information I've found on the topic. (Idk if this classifies the question as a duplicate)

[16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues)

Comment: Doesn't the question specifically mention that restarting network-manager doesn't work for them?

Comment: @jawtheshark Pretty sure that was an edit, I dont remember reading that part when originally answering.

Comment: Your comment came up in a review, so that's why I replied instead of downvoting.

Comment: @jawtheshark I would have just commented but all of my rep points are in stack overflows main branch. :/

Comment: Purely my opinion - I don't think it's an issue with the drivers being that this is an issue for quite a few Ubuntu users.