# Realtek RTL8188EE not working properly on 16.10 nor 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, 16.10

So I have an Asus x200M which I bought a couple of years ago. I used Windows 10 (which worked fine) until a couple of days ago when I decided to switch to Ubuntu 16.04. I made the switch and everything worked fine until I realized that the wifi was working very badly and that after waking from hibernation the icon would change as if my connection was a wired one instead of a wireless one.

I checked some posts and I found that some people were having the same problem as me. One recommended upgrading the distro might solve the problem. I upgraded to 16.10 and nothing. Further investigation led me to check my wifi card using

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

and with that I get the following:

```
      *-network NO RECLAMADO    
   descripción: Network controller
   producto: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
   fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
   versión: 01
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuración: latency=0
   recursos: ioport:e000(size=256) memoria:d0700000-d0703fff

    *-network
   descripción: Ethernet interface
   producto: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   id físico: 0.2
   información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.2
   nombre lógico: enp3s0f2
   versión: 06
   serie: 10:c3:7b:b3:0c:5d
   tamaño: 100Mbit/s
   capacidad: 100Mbit/s
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 ip=192.168.0.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   recursos: irq:90 ioport:d000(size=256) memoria:d0614000-d0614fff memoria:d0610000-d0613fff
```

which leads me to believe that my wireless adapter is the Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter. Further googling action led me to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues) in which a user sugests doing the following in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git dkms
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd /rtlwifi_new
make
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

And I tried that, and I get the following

```
mario@mario-X200MA:~/rtlwifi_new$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/build M=/home/mario/rtlwifi_new     modules
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 14 modules
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
mario@mario-X200MA:~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
[sudo] password for mario: 
mario@mario-X200MA:~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/build M=/home/mario/rtlwifi_new   modules
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 14 modules
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
Install rtlwifi SUCCESS
mario@mario-X200MA:~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
insmod /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-     generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8188ee': Required key not available
```

The last line is the one that baffles me, because it tells me that the required key is not available. I did some more googling and found that with **mokutil** I could disable the Secure Boot, but I ran that in a terminal and it outputs

```
This system does't support Secure Boot
```

So my question is, what do I do now? Do I try to sign the package myself? Do I even need to sign it, given that my computer doesn't support Secure Boot? Have I followed a wrong path?

**[EDIT: So  after tinkering with the BIOS I found out that the Secure Boot option is a bit difficult to find, but there it is, under a couple other options]**

So I was able to try the method stated above, and while it did change the driver, it did not solve the problem. I've been having some packet loss that gets worse from time to time. Right now is at 13%.

Comment: You have to turn off secure boot in your BIOS. Cheers, Al

Comment: If you don't see the option to disable secure boot in your BIOS, under the security tab, you may have to jump through hoops like this https://www.all4os.com/windows/disable-asus-motherboards-uefi-secure-boot.html to disable it. Cheers, Al

Comment: Was the link that I sent you about secure boot what helped you? Are you on cable or DSL? If you hardwire with an ethernet cable, does it work better? Are you using WPA2-AES for your wireless connection? What router do you have? If you reply in the comments, please start with @heynnema or I may miss your reply. Cheers, Al