# Constantly lost of the internet connection with the wifi after install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I have a laptop Lenovo Y700 and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I'm having issues with the Wifi.

The wireless connection looks good but I cannot connect to Internet sometimes. To fix it, I do...

```
service network-manager restart
```

It works for some minutes but later the same problem and I have to restart again and again, and this is really annoying.

I tried the solutions given [in this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/762198/635403) but the problem continues.

This is the information of my PC...

```
##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3832]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b512 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0480:a006 Toshiba America Inc External Disk 1.5TB
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8821ae             225280  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    20480  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.178.45  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d4e4:4af1:7b11:9187/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2003:86:6676:2d00:c28c:48ef:cfeb:a014/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11509 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10836 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6457711 (6.4 MB)  TX bytes:1833640 (1.8 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 7362 SL"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search fritz.box

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      3742     1  1 01:01 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8821ae
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-57-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     FRITZ!Box 7362 SL
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ac016a1a-695a-461b-adf1-cfb7dc169115
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ac016a1a-695a-461b-adf1-cfb7dc169115 | FRITZ!Box 7362 SL
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.178.45/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.178.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.178.45
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.178.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 756000
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 432000
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1484265694
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.178.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       next_server = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 864000
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2003:86:6676:2d00:c28c:48ef:cfeb:a014/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::d4e4:4af1:7b11:9187/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::3a10:d5ff:fe44:ca0b
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2003:86:6676:2d00::/64, nh = fe80::3a10:d5ff:fe44:ca0b, mt = 600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd00::3a10:d5ff:fe44:ca0b
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fd00::3a10:d5ff:fe44:ca0b
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:38:10:d5:44:ca:b
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:1e:50:81:97:69:9e:72:c:35:a0:90:82:3a:bb:f6:fd

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
DIRECT-A6-HP OfficeJet 3830  <MAC 'DIRECT-A6-HP OfficeJet 3830' [AN1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no        
HITRON-CAE0                  <MAC 'HITRON-CAE0' [AN2]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Vodafone Homespot            <MAC 'Vodafone Homespot' [AN3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  --         no        
Vodafone Hotspot             <MAC 'Vodafone Hotspot' [AN4]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  --         no        
FRITZ!Box 7362 SL            <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA2       yes     * 
WLAN-34FF25                  <MAC 'WLAN-34FF25' [AN6]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
Vodafone Hotspot             <MAC 'Vodafone Hotspot' [AN7]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  --         no        
KDG-879CF                    <MAC 'KDG-879CF' [AN8]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
KD-WLAN-9154 AO              <MAC 'KD-WLAN-9154 AO' [AN9]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360      <MAC 'FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360' [AN10]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
FRITZ!Box 7330               <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7330' [AN11]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Vodafone Hotspot             <MAC 'Vodafone Hotspot' [AN12]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  --         no        
KabelBox-FEE0                <MAC 'KabelBox-FEE0' [AN13]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
KDG-C6833                    <MAC 'KDG-C6833' [AN14]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FRITZ!Box 7362 SL]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FRITZ!Box 7362 SL | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=FRITZ!Box 7362 SL
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8821ae]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8821ae 802.11ac PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     B9E24DCC76240A48AEEF94E
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-57-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           int_clear:Set to 0 to disable interrupt clear before set (default 1)
 (bool)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     A96EBF28EBD4603749D5EC3
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-57-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     81DBE78DD4871E3EC5F2E9D
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-57-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     0B114888238BEBBE8043BC5
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-57-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     FD4B9DA2F385F0531B5CB0B
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-57-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8821ae]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: N
int_clear: Y
ips: Y
msi: Y
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist ideapad-laptop

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf]
blacklist ideapad_laptop

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0.conf]
blacklist gspca_kinect

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ae.conf]
options rtl8821ae fwlps=N

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8821ae"

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  580.057551] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
[  580.148045] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2172.369033] wlp2s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> lost
[ 2175.368524] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]>
[ 2175.368931] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[ 2175.471452] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (try 2/3)
[ 2175.575371] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (try 3/3)
[ 2175.679419] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> timed out
[ 2188.195594] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 4 times)
[ 2876.994331] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[ 2877.010288] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down
[ 2877.010405] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[ 2877.105114] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 2880.173762] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]>
[ 2880.177260] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[ 2880.191121] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2880.195454] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[ 2880.204365] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=7)
[ 2880.264011] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2880.264042] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 3241.188389] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3261.305400] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 3261.311629] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[ 3261.327516] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down
[ 3261.327692] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[ 3261.448825] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 3274.151447] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]>
[ 3278.916185] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[ 3278.926662] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 3278.928265] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[ 3278.941799] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' [AN5]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
[ 3279.050669] wlp2s0: associated
[ 3279.050732] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks chili555, I edited my post to include the information got it from your Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you disable power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

In fact, in the data you submitted, we see *ten* networks, including the one you are connected to, that are on channel 1. In your case, I suggest, channel 6 or 12 and *not* 1.

Reboot the router and let us hear your report.

If this is ineffective or only partially effective, then install a better driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Reboot and tell us if connectivity is improved.

Comment: Hi Chili555, I did what you said but I continue having the same issue. My others devices at home work perfect and the same computer if I turn on Windows also work good. Do you have others clues? Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: After doing that, looks much better, I have another PC with Ubuntu and I do ping to google with both PCs, in the last hour I had just one interruption with the one I'm having problems. I will accept your answer. Thanks for your help.