# After Ubuntu 14.04.04 LTS install no internet access

Tags: 14.04, internet

I recently imaged Ubuntu  a Dell Vostro 3900 Series with an Intel Core i3-4170 CPU @3.70GHz x 4 (32-bit). After installing we do not have internet access wired or wireless.

Referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues/768268#comment1186039_768268), we tried:
sudo lshw -class network
and got the following product info:
Product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
configuration includes
driver=r8169
firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13

Then created a file config in /etc/pm/config.d/
And entered SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8168g" and saved
Then ran the following command:
echo "options rtl8168g fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

And then rebooted, but it didn't change.

I feel sure you're going to tell us that this is a duplicate question, but it's hard to see what the relevant piece is from all the suggestions offered on the various questions that have some degree of overlap with this one.

Anyway, any help that can be provided is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We found the answer to this question on a forum related to the Koha Library system. The Ubuntu package we installed was a LiveCD installation package of Koha 3.22.6 which included Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The solution was to run the following command:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf

Follow the instructions on the prompt and respond Yes and OK as requested. Then reboot.