# Wifi not auto connecting

Tags: networking, wireless

I've got 16.10 installed on a HP laptop for just a couple days now.  Yesterday, I had to do some re-configuring to my house Wifi system, and oddly now, when the laptop boots it does not auto-connect the wifi.  The box is checked to do that, and indeed if I click the drop box, it connects.

So why not the auto-connect?  What did I break?

WiFi: rtl8723be

Comment: What re-configuring exactly? Deleting the connection and adding it again is probably where you should start troubleshooting.

Comment: That came to mind and I tried it...  gotta say it didn't give up without a struggle.  I'd delete the connection, and it'd still be there.  When I did get it deleted and made a new connection, it wouldn't connect at all.  Grrr.   Finally, I booted from my USB with trial Ubuntu, that wifi'd fine.  Booted again, and now I have wifi again.  I dunno, bizarre.  All I'd done to the wifi system itself was set a password.  I live in the middle of nowhere and hadn't felt the need.

Comment: Another point - when I'd boot the laptop in Windows it would show a much stronger wifi signal than when in Ubuntu.  When I was in trial Ubuntu the signal showed strong, and now the signal is still strong.   The laptop is maybe 6 feet from the AP.  Is there maybe some signal booster thing that was stuck off?

Comment: That suggests yo may not bee using the best driver. Please post details about your WiFi device.

Comment: The show connection says its rtl8723be driver.  I'll be happy to provide any other details if you explain how to get the info.  But I do have another clue, I think I've seen other questions - it seems the wifi doesn't wake up properly after the screen sleep.  In "Power" when plugged in, its set to not suspend, but in "Brightness and Lock" the screen goes off in 10 minutes.  Paying attention to it, when I bring the screen back the icon says it has a connection, but Chromium can't connect.  If I disconnect and reconnect it Chromium works again. After a longer time, wifi can't reconnect.

Comment: Looks like there were multiple problems - something did get messed up when I put the WPA password in, but also others are having problems with the sleep thing too.  This answer seems to have fix that aspect: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues  Probably the same answer.  The hard part was getting it untangled.  Thanks for your assistance @CelticWarrior !