# Ubuntu 16.04 - Losing internet connection randomly

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, network-manager, internet

i i'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Desktop PC using a Wireless USB Dongle (Asus USB-N53 on 5 GHZ).

I started getting internet disconnections often and the only way for me to get it working again is to `sudo service network-manager restart`. I don't remember facing this issue when i was using 14.04 (on the same hardware), and even with 16.04 they were not that often in the beginning.

```
psychok7@Desktop:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: bc:ae:c5:aa:24:72
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:37 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:f6fff000-f6ffffff memory:f6ff8000-f6ffbfff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.6
       logical name: wlx10bf485b4bfb
       serial: 10:bf:48:5b:4b:fb
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.4.0-66-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.2.148 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

I have other devices connected to the same router and none have that problem.

Any ideas on how i can fix this??

UPDATE:
i am now trying this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/768268/59618) to see if my issue goes away but replaced the driver with `rt2800usb`