# 16.04 wifi network issues

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I'm having a Wi-Fi problem and it seems to be with the driver. Every now and then the Wi-Fi randomly drops and it act like I don't even have a Wi-Fi card in the computer. I found `sudo service-network manager restart`, works to get it back up.  I am, however looking for a better solution and found [16.04 LTS wifi connection issues with Realtek RTL8723BE adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues).

The issue I keep incuring is every time I try to create any file in terminal I just get the message "no such file or directory". I'm trying to figure out what i need to do to actually make this work so I don't have to constantly open the terminal to reset the network manager manually. Below is my network card information. Removed serial for security reasons.

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=4.8.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.8.19.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:45 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 07
       serial: 
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b00fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

Comment: You get the "No such file or directory" error when attempting to add `SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"` to `/etc/pm/config.d/config`?
please post the output of `ls /etc/pm/*`

Comment: `/etc/pm/config.d:

/etc/pm/power.d:

/etc/pm/sleep.d:
10_grub-common  10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate  novatel_3g_suspend
`

Comment: Okay so you should be able to create `/etc/pm/config.d/config` by running `vim /etc/pm/config.d/config` and adding `SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"`. You can change `vim` to be your editor of choice such as `nano`. If you get the `"No such file or directory"` error again, make sure that you don't have any spelling or grammar mistakes in the path such extra spaces.

Comment: the vim solution just lets me open a file for editing in terminal but it doesnt seem to do anything beyond that.

Comment: If you don't know the commands to edit documents with `vim`, I'd suggest you use `nano` instead (`nano /etc/pm/config.d/config`).

Comment: I was able to get the file made, however i still randomly lose wifi capability.